# creating a mysql.cnf file for import

Tags: mysql

I have created a config file for dumping .sql with no password prompt, is it possible to do this when using import?

I have read somewhere to just add on the cnf file "mysqlimport" then the credential details, but gets me back with an mysql error code 2000 'user'@'localhost' access denied, using password (NO).

I also tried granting this user access, but no success. This user is different from the user I use for sql dumps.

This is how I run the import command:

```
mysqlimport --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysql/mysqlimport.cnf reports < /tmp/testdump.sql
```

error message is

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: you should add `[mysqlimport]`, not `mysqlimport`, see [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html)

Comment: I did add [mysqlimport], but what option do I use so it can read the cnf file? is it still --defaults-extra-file= ?

Comment: this is how I run the import command mysqlimport --defaults-extra-file=~/.mysql/mysqlimport.cnf reports < /tmp/testdump.sql

error message is ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to not use the cnf file, instead I used .yaml in solving this.

Thanks for answering.